# Console shows different output for getElementsBy ... causes Array.prototype.slice.call to fail on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a function to gather all anchor elements and write listeners for them.
If I refresh the browser (latest versions of Chrome and Firefox on Mac), sometimes the collection of elements is displayed differently and causes my call to Array.prototype.slice to return an empty array.

```
function toArray(arr) { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr); }

let anchors = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) 
{ 
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', clicked, false); 
}
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
console.log(anchors);
```

When working properly (the listeners are added), the console looks like this:
[image: correct console output]

But when I refresh the browser, much of the time it comes back looking like this:
[image: incorrect console output]

If I expand the array output, it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Why are they sometimes different? Is there a way to always get the correct result?

Comment: Btw, the modern way of writing this `toArray` is `Array.from` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your script should wait for the page to finish loading before any call to `getElementsByTagName`. Otherwise, many `a` elements may not have been loaded yet, and `getElementsByTagName` will not retrieve them.

So, wrap your code in an onload event handler, e.g.:

```
onload = function() {
    let anchors = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) 
    { 
        anchors[i].addEventListener('click', clicked, false); 
    }
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
    console.log(anchors);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This sent me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting / marking as answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Per the feedback from Anis, I wrapped the code in a function called writeListeners() and tried calling it two different ways:

1. Adding an onload attribute for the script itself in the header and 
   `<script onload="writeListeners();" src="file"></script>`
   Didn't work because the script was loading before DOM completed.
2. Part of an existing DOMContentLoaded function at the end of the file. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {writeListeners();});` At first this failed because writeListeners was not yet defined. This was happening because the script that contains the function was tagged with async and loading after DOMContentLoaded. I removed the async tag to ensure the script loads earlier and now it works.